# Is Static Dynamic Array not allowed in RPGLE sub-procedure

Tags: rpgle

SEQ is throwing a RNF3772 error if I try to declare a Static Dynamic array in a RPGLE sub-procedure.  Is static dynamic array not allowed in sub-procedure?

Below is an example of what I entered in SEQ.  The error that I got is "The keyword is not allowed following keyword STATIC; keyword is ignored."

```
P proc1           B                                                    
D                 pi                                                   
D myArray         s             10    dim(1000) static based(myArray_p)

P                 E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define your array as based, but have it retain its values between calls, you have to define the **basing pointer** as static. It will probably be impossible to free the allocated storage except by reclaiming the activation group, unless your procedure has a way of knowing the array is no longer needed for future calls.

Comment: I was getting ready to add this to my answer :)  It's kind of mentioned as part of the open source use.  But I was going to call it out.

Comment: interesting.  That actually work.  Then again, it's Barbara, why do I even question that.

Comment: @Barbara Morris would it be possible to add a parameter to the static keyword that will allow developer to specify the persistent 
 scope?  For example: static(*job) or static(*actGrpDfn) or static(*callLvl).

Comment: I went ahead and created a change request for this: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=141840

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid that your RFE will be rejected. That is not feasible. 

By the way, you actually opened your RFE against RDi. (Don't worry, we'll route it to the RPG compiler.) 

When opening RFEs for the RPG compiler, choose 

Brand: Servers and Systems Software
Product family: Power Systems;
Product: IBM i;
Component: Languages - RPG;

Comment: rejected because it is not feasible or rejected because there is no reason to have such feature?

Answer (score 4):

`static` means the memory is kept (allocated) locally between calls
`based` means that no memory is allocated locally

So yeah, the two are mutually exclusive...

Unless you're %alloc() memory yourself, there's no dynamic arrays in RPG...I think even the new "dynamic arrays" in 7.4 actually just allocate the max memory.  What's nice is they keep track of how many elements are used automatically.

**edit2** As Barbara called out, if you are doing %Alloc()/%Realloc() yourself, then all you need is the basing pointer declared `static`  I'd include a parm to indicate the memory should be cleaned up.

```
P proc1           B                                                    
D                 pi                 
d  cleanUp                        n   value

D myArray         s             10    dim(1000) based(myArray_p)
d myArray_p       s               *   static
  if cleanUp;
     dealloc(myArray_p);
     return;
  endif;

P                 E
```

Just use static.  Same memory requirements as if you'd used a global variable, but hidden inside the procedure.

If you really want dynamic arrays, you could build your own routines in a *SRVPGM to use.  Or you could make use of some open source.
[RPG Next Gen - Vector](http://rpgnextgen.com/index.php?content=vector)
[RPG Array List/Linked List](https://github.com/lppedd/RPG)
[RPGMap](https://github.com/jerps/RpgMap)
[Dynamic Array using a user space](https://mowyourlawn.com/RPGDynamicArrays.html)

With an actual dynamic array, you'd likely end up with a pointer (or maybe an integer) variable in your procedure that you'd want defined as `STATIC` so that it remains between calls.

You'll also need to consider how to clean up the memory when you are done.

Comment: So, I need an array to keep track of things within a sub-procedure.  This array is only used in this sub-procedure.  Declare it in this sub-procedure seems like a right thing to do.  The array needs to be dynamic because, depending on the condition, it could range from a few to possibly tens of thousands. The procedure will be repetitively called and elements in the array needs to be kept in between called.  Is there no way to achieve such, short of declaring it as a global variable or making it a non dynamic array?

Comment: Yes, by dynamic array, I mean using %alloc(),%realloc(), and dealloc to dynamically get the desire array size at run time.  Most our interactive programs run in QILE activation group and is no different for this program that I'm dealing with.  If I use static keyword only, the array size will be the max fixed size, and this big chunk of memory will be allocated for the life of the QILE activation group, which is basically till user signoff from the application, sounded so wasteful.

Comment: ah, linked list, taking me back to my college years I see.  It is a bit of an over killed solution.  I guess I'll just go with the global array option.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a %dealloc BIF.  There is only dealloc opcode.

Comment: The amount of static storage is the same for a global array or a static array in the subprocedure.

Comment: @BarbaraMorris can you confirm that still applies to the new "dynamic" arrays also?

Comment: The dynamic arrays (defined with DIM(*VAR) or DIM(*AUTO)) use heap storage for the actual array data. But the information maintained by the compiler -about- the current state of the array is in either static or automatic storage depending on the STATIC keyword. The amount of heap storage allocated for the array isn't necessarily the maximum size of the array; it might grow over time. The amount of heap and static or automatic storage used by a dynamic array is the same for a global or local array.